# display limited words from ES field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Mpdreamz/NEST for integrating Elasticsearch in C# . Is there any way to limit the number of words in a result  string of query??

For example I have a field named 'Content' in ES and I need to dispaly 30 words of 'Content' matching 'sensex' from my index.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Anyone Please share a way to achieve this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't so easily even within Elasticsearch itself.

You have three options

1. Force excerpts by using highlighting
2. Try to use script_fields to return the first 30 words
3. At index time add another field that has just the first 30 words

Eventhough the first two are possible to do with NEST i would go for the third option since it won't incur a performance penalty at query time.